# Possible Javascript "replace" function bug in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Open your Chrome browser, try this:

```
'x </script>'.replace(/x/,'\'$\'')  ---> "' </script> </script>"
```

And this one:

```
'x'.replace(/x/,'$$') --> "$"
```

In IE, everything is correct.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I tested with Edge, no such issue.

Comment: `$` is a special character in string.replace, and `$$` is the way that you escape it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter . IE apparently does not implement this.

Comment: That's a good answer. But Edge does not work that way, creating compatibility issues. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: Looks like we can use the function as replacement to avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nicholas's good answer. function can be used as replacement parameter to avoid this issue.